# How to slice an array of member roles to ten in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

I have this piece of code and it is working perfectly fine until it reaches its limit of `1024` as the member's roles are displayed in an `addField` value. It gives me the error when a member owns so many roles in the guild. What I'm trying to do is how the bot will send the **first 10** roles that the member has and if it is more than that it'll provide the roles and continue the message with `<numbers> more`

`const roles = member.roles.cache.filter(r => r.id !== message.guild.id).map(r => r).join(" ")`

Comment: Look at `Array.prototype.slice`.

Comment: Thanks for that. So I tried doing `slice(2, 10)` but when a member has below `10` roles, it returns as `No Roles`

Answer (score 1):

@fubar has brought up that you can use [`Array#slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to achieve this. The reason why it's not working for you and returning an empty array (`[]`) is probably because you are testing your code on a guild member that has less than 3 roles. The `slice` method will return an empty array when its array's length is shorter than its `start` parameter. In your case, you supplied `2` when you should've supplied `0`. So, this phenomenon does not occur exactly when a guild member has less than 10 roles as you say.

Your code also appears to have redundancies. Your [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method will never reduce the size of the array returned by [`GuildMemberRoleManager#cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache) because the ID of a guild would already realistically never match the ID of one of that guild's roles. Also, your [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) method does not actually return an array containing different values - the callback function you pass in just returns the same value it receives. Both these chained calls can be safely removed and your code's behaviour will remain the same.

That said, here's the updated code:

```
const rolesToDisplay = member.roles.cache.array().slice(0, 10); //start at index 0 and end before index 10
```

Comment: I tried using your code but sadly it's returning as `not a function`

Comment: Can you tell me the full error message? My guess is that something along the way is `undefined` in your code.

Comment: Note that I changed the name of that constant to be more specific - from `roles` (which was a string) to `rolesToDisplay` (which is an array). You will have to make any necessary changes to the rest of your code.

Comment: This is the whole error: `TypeError: member.roles.cache.slice is not a function`

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. `.cache` returns a `Collection`, not an array, which doesn't have a `.slice()` function in itself. I will update my answer. Such error messages are invaluable in determining the cause of a problem.

Comment: My `userinfo` has 2 functions. 1 is for sending the correct and detailed info and 1 is for sending if an error has occurred; and the second one is sending. I'm not getting any errors. 

PS. 
I wrap it with the `try...catch` and still not giving me any errors

Comment: With the updated answer, what seems to be the problem? Is your code catching and suppressing some other error but not logging it properly? It's hard to say from only one line of your code.

Comment: Your outer catch block will not run if your inner try-catch has already caught the error. Wha you could do instead is add a `console.error` in the inner catch block. But if you say the second "function" is sending aka your embed sends but only partially filled in, it would be caused by an error within the inner try-catch. My guess is that, since you are trying to interpolate the entire `rolesToDisplay` array as part of your field, it way exceeds the character limit (think `[{...},{...},...]` with all of each role's properties).

Comment: By the way, I would not recommend overwriting guild members' status properties directly. They are passed around by reference so you may mess up other parts of your or the library's code. Since you already declare a `status` variable and use that for interpolating when constructing your embed, you can simply declare that variable prior to your 4 overwrites, then define the `status` variable in each line instead of doing an overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

Since `member.roles.cache` returns a Collection, you can use the [`first() method`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=first) to pull the first X roles. In your case, you wanted to retrieve the first ten roles; so, you would use `member.roles.cache.first(10)`. This returns a collection of the first ten roles from the cache.

For the `<numbers> more` part, you can use `member.roles.cache.size` in an if condition to decide how you want to split things up.

Comment: Thanks for info, and, you can use .first(10) then .sort, etc.